# What can I store a single element in a Collection?

Tags: java, collections

I've got a DTO object used to get data from my server. It can be used for one or several elements. This DTO encapsulate a `Collection` containing the data.

When my DTO brings me only one element, how should I store it?

Sample code:

```
public class DataDTO implements Serializable
{
    private Collection<Data> data;

    public DataDTO()
    {
    }

    public Collection<Data> getData()
    {
        return data;
    }


    public void setData(Collection<Data> data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }


    public void setData(Data singleData)
    {
        // At this time I use an ArrayList initialized with a capacity of 1
        this.data = new ArrayList<Data>(1);
        this.data.add(singleData);
    }
}
```

Comment: What about using `Array`?

Comment: One element is not a Collection :P

Comment: I know that one element is not a collection, but I do not want to add a special DTO object just for the case where I've got only one element ^^

Comment: @Arpit why would you want to do that? It wouldn't be a `Collection`.

Comment: @FranMontero a `Collection` containing a single element is still a `Collection` - it is a "singleton". You might argue that a singleton is an adapter pattern for a single element to the `Collection` API but that doesn't change the fact that it conforms to the `Collection` API and therefore _is a_ `Collection`...

Comment: An empty collection is still a collection.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use singleton methods from **Collections** class.

**singletonList**  : Returns an immutable list containing only the specified object. The returned list is serializable.

**singleton** : Returns an immutable set containing only the specified object. The returned set is serializable.

**singletonMap** : Returns an immutable map, mapping only the specified key to the specified value. The returned map is serializable.

Comment: What are the differences in terms of memory space and performances ?

Comment: @Sara absolutely none. Take a look at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Collections.java?av=f) - the `singletonXXX` classes are just simple adapters to different `interface` types - you select one based on whether you want to use the `Set` API or the `List` API - `Map` is obviously not a `Collection`.

Answer (score 5):

The question is, what do you want to do later with it? Is there a chance that you migh add another element? If not, you could use

`this.data = Collections.singletonList( singleData );`

If there is a chance that you might want to add elements later, then it's the typical question what List implementation to use, ArrayList is fine for many cases.

Comment: Or `Collections.singleton` to the same effect.